# Azure AKS - preview Istio service mesh add on

Tags: azure-aks, istio

I have done the istio service mesh add on to the my aks cluster that comes as preview. I'm able to access the product page and I see the sidecar is running with the services. how to access to service mesh UI and check the service mesh, traffic routing configurations. please share if I missed any.

Comment: In order access to [service mesh UI](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/) and check the service mesh, install [Kiali](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/kiali/#installation)

Comment: Reference Document-

[Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) with Istio Service Mesh: A Comprehensive Guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-kubernetes-service-aks-istio-mesh-comprehensive-cristofolini/)

[MS Doc- Deploy Istio-based service mesh add-on for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-deploy-addon)

[Visualizing your mesh with Kiali](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/)

[Installation via Istio addon](https://kiali.io/docs/installation/quick-start/)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you have already installed Istio and can access the product page. I am not showing the entire Istio setup, Skipping to the point- In order access to [service mesh UI](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/) and check the service mesh, install [Kiali](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/kiali/#installation) using either

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.20/samples/addons/kiali.yaml
```

or via helm

```
helm install \
  --namespace istio-system \
  --set auth.strategy="anonymous" \
  --repo https://kiali.org/helm-charts \
  kiali-server \
  kiali-server
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

kubectl port-forward svc/kiali 20001:20001 -n [image]
Once you access Kiali, you can explore various aspects of your service mesh.
[image]

The dashboard provides views for graphs, applications, workloads, services, and Istio configurations.

Reference Document-

[Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) with Istio Service Mesh: A Comprehensive Guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-kubernetes-service-aks-istio-mesh-comprehensive-cristofolini/)

[MS Doc- Deploy Istio-based service mesh add-on for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-deploy-addon)

[Visualizing your mesh with Kiali](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/)

[Installation via Istio addon](https://kiali.io/docs/installation/quick-start/)